# Return string in solidity 0.5.0. Data location must be "memory" for return parameter in function

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

How to return string in 0.5.0 solidity compiler version?

```
contract Test {
    string public text = 'show me';
    function  test() public view returns (string) {
        return text;
    }
}
```

I got error message:

```
TypeError: Data location must be "memory" for return parameter in function, but none was given.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just need to add `memory` after `string`, like this:

```
function test() public view returns (string memory) {
```

Another changes:
https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.0/050-breaking-changes.html#interoperability

Answer (score 1):

```
//The version I have used is 0.5.2

pragma solidity ^0.5.2;

contract Inbox{


string public message;

//**Constructor** must be defined using “constructor” keyword

//**In version 0.5.0 or above** it is **mandatory to use “memory” keyword** so as to 
//**explicitly mention the data location**

//you are free to remove the keyword and try for yourself

 constructor (string memory initialMessage) public{
 message=initialMessage;
 }

 function setMessage(string memory newMessage)public{
 message=newMessage;

 }

 function getMessage()public view returns(string memory){
 return message;
 }}
```